# Printing of exception subclasses is not a tuple of arguments

Tags: python, exception, overloading

For the exceptions used in a project:

```py
class SwitcherError(Exception):
    pass


class ApiError(SwitcherError):
   pass



class ApiHTTPError(ApiError):
    def __init__(self, message=None, text=None, api_errors=None):
        self.text = text
        self.message = message
        self.errors = api_errors


class ApiJsonError(ApiError):
    def __init__(self, message=None, text=None):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.text = text
```

If I print out the error using super I don't seem to get a print of a tuple of the arguments (as defined by BaseException) but I do if I don't use super() and just override the arguments directly in the initialiser.
I'm not clear why that is and how I should be writing my classes.

Where did 'text' go in the output?

```py
try:
    raise ApiJsonError('msg', 'text')
except ApiJsonError as e:
    print(e)
>>> 'msg'
```

where as the below is as expected

```py
try:
    raise ApiHTTPError('msg', 'text')
except ApiHTTPError as e:
    print(e)

>>>('msg', 'text')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `ApiJsonError.__str__`:

```
class ApiJsonError(ApiError):
    def __init__(self, message=None, text=None):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.text = text
    def __str__(self):
        return str((*self.args, self.text))
```

Which produces:

```
>>> try:
...     raise ApiJsonError('msg', 'text')
... except ApiJsonError as e:
...     print(e)
... 
('msg', 'text')
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> The `except` clause may specify a variable after the exception name. The variable is bound to an exception instance with the arguments stored in `instance.args`. **For convenience, the exception instance defines `__str__()` so the arguments can be printed directly without having to reference `.args`.**

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I'm trying to understand the why the output is different too? ie why they both don't output ('msg', 'text')

Comment: Because `Exception.__str__` will print only `message` by default, since that is the `args` that you are passing to `super().__init__()`.

Comment: Ah so I misunderstood. I thought the child class would inherit __str__() and it execute on that class, ie with both arguments from it's __init__()

Comment: Because you are only passing `message` to the parent class(s), that is all their own `__str__` "know" as `args`.

Comment: ok so when print(e) is called it calls __str__ on the ApiJsonError class which it doesn't find so then it looks in it's parent class, ApiError where it finds __str__ and then executes it - which only knows of message from the ApiError __init__ class.   And not as I thought ApiJsonError gets a copy of __str__ from it's parent so print(e) executes __str__ on the ApiJsonError class.

Comment: You got it.  That's why you need to write your own `__str__` for `ApiJsonError`.

Comment: thanks I think I thought inheritance made the inherited methods sit on the lowest level - the child class- rather than the lookup is referred upto the parent. Thanks for clarifying.